# Google sheet sorting a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets

Sheet 1 = SVerB-leden

Automatic sorting wanted on column 1

Sheet 2= Verjaardag

Automatic sorting wanted on column 2.

I found a script that automatically sorts a given column alphabetically on editing. I want however 1 sheet sorted on the first column, and another sheet on the 2 cloumn.

The script  i found does it for all sheets.
Is it possible to change this in a way that it works ?

```
 /**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  var tableRange = "B2:V500"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rngEdited = event.range;
  var sheetBeingEdited = rngEdited.getSheet().getName();
  Logger.log('rngEdited: ' + rngEdited);
  Logger.log('sheetBeingEdited: ' + sheetBeingEdited);

  var colEdited = editedCell.getColumn();
  var columnToSortBy;
  var tableRange;

  if (sheetBeingEdited === 'SVerB-leden') {
    columnToSortBy = 1;
    tableRange = "B2:V500"; // What to sort.
    if (colEdited === columnToSortBy) {
      sortColumn(columnToSortBy, tableRange, sheet);
    };
  } else if (sheetBeingEdited === 'Verjaardag') {
    columnToSortBy = 2;
    tableRange = "B2:V500"; // What to sort.
    if (colEdited === columnToSortBy) {
      sortColumn(columnToSortBy, tableRange, sheet);
    };
  };  
};

function sortColumn(colNmbr, rngToSort, sh) {
  var range = sh.getRange(rngToSort);
  range.sort( { column : colNmbr, ascending: true } );
};
```

Comment: I am from the time that dBase III and Clipper were used so i need this help and appriate it.. :-). I get an error on var rngEdited = event.range;

Comment: If you are running the code from the code editor to test it, the `event` object will be empty.  The `event` object is only passed in when you've actually edited the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

This sub works effectively in all my projects

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.sort(1, false);   // Sorting by 1st column, change to 2 for the second //
  });
}
```